# Как передать в rails на страницу index.html.erb вложенные сущности?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет. Уже пару недель не получается сделать одну штуку, прошу помощи.
Делаю приложение на rails с Туду-листами. Туду-листов можно создавать сколько-угодно, и в каждом Туду-листе можно создавать свои задачи.

Файл роутов выглядит так:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get 'users/new'
  resources :todo_lists do 
    resources :todo_items do
        member do
            patch :complete
        end
    end
  end

  root "todo_lists#index"
end
```

Но есть проблема: я хочу вывести на страницу index не только TodoLists, но и TodoItems для каждого листа. Как мне передать на todo_lists#index и todo_list, и его айтемы?

**Контроллер TodoLists:**

```
class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    if user_signed_in?  
        @todo_lists = TodoList.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
  end    
end
```

**Модель TodoList:**

```
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :todo_items
end
```

**Модель TodoItem**

```
class TodoItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :todo_list     
end
```

Далее вью. Для удобства разбила index.html.erb и _todo_list.html.erb, лежат в одной папке:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
        <%= render "todo_list", todo_list: todo_list %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="main-button-wrapper">
        <button id="main-button">
            <%= link_to "Add TODO List", new_todo_list_path %>
        </button>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'layouts/static_home_page' %>
<% end %>
```

**_todo_list.html.erb**

```
<div class="index_row clearfix" id="list-id-<%=todo_list.id%>">
    <h2 class="work-task--top-panel_title"><%= link_to todo_list.title, todo_list %></h2>
    <div class="top-panel_buttons">
        <%= link_to image_tag("#"), edit_todo_list_path(todo_list) %>
        <%= link_to image_tag("#"), todo_list_path(todo_list), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="work-task--input-field" id="list">
    <%= form_for([todo_list, todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New TODO" %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="work-task--list">
    <div class="work-task--list__wrapper first-column">

    <%= render todo_list.todo_items, todo_list: @todo_list %>

    </div>
</div>
```

> <%= render todo_list.todo_items, **todo_list: @todo_list** <--- одна из неудачных попыток передать в Todo Items todo_list_id.

***-Этот лежит в отдельной папке todo_items-***
**_todo_item.html.erb**

```
<div class="row clearfix flex-class">
    <% if todo_item.completed? %>       
        <div class="complete">
            <%= link_to complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), remote: true, method: :patch do %>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
            <% end %>
        </div>
                
        <div class="todo_item" style="opacity: 0.4;"><strike><%= todo_item.content %></strike></div>

        <div class="move show-button">
           <%= link_to image_tag("#")%>
        </div>

        <div class="edit show-button">
           <%= link_to image_tag("#"), edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list) %>
        </div>
                
        <div class="trash show-button">
           <%= link_to image_tag("#"), todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "Are you sure?", class: "deleteAction" } %>
        </div>
    
    <% else %>
        <div class="complete">
          <%= link_to "Complete", complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), remote: true, method: :patch %>
        </div>

        <div class="todo_item">
          <%= todo_item.content %>
        </div>

        <div class="move show-button">
          <%= link_to image_tag("#") %>
        </div>

        <div class="edit show-button">
          <%= link_to image_tag("#"), edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list) %>
        </div>

        <div class="trash show-button">
            <%= link_to image_tag("#"), todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "Are you sure?", class: "deleteAction" } %>
        </div>
    <% end %>     
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем поняла. На `/todo_lists` вы хотите у каждого листа отобразить его айтемы? Или просто под списком листов сделать отдельный общий список айтемов?

Comment: Хочу отобразить у каждого листа свои айтемы.

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу код контроллера, моделей и вьюшки, пожалуйста. Тогда смогу вам помочь

Comment: Файлы добавила. Заранее Вам большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто, `_todo_item.html.erb` - это партиал, вам надо отрендерить его для каждого айтема. У вас это не получается из-за того, что в партиале вы пытаетесь использовать instance variable `@todo_list`.

Это плохая практика, партиалы могут рендериться в очень разных частях проекта, бывает очень сложно отследить, откуда именно прилетает эта переменная. Поэтому в партиалах принято использовать только локальные переменные и передавать их в партиал при рендеринге.

Во-первых, замените в _todo_item.html.erb `@todo_list` на `todo_list`

Во-вторых, замените

```
<%= render todo_list.todo_items, todo_list: @todo_list %>
```

на

```
<%= render partial: 'todo_items/todo_item', collection: todo_list.todo_items, 
    as: :todo_item, locals: { todo_list: todo_list } %>
```

В-третьих, сделайте то же самое для всех остальных партиалов в проекте

Более подробно про работу с партиалами можно почитать в [официальных доках](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: Ему опять что-то не нравится, все еще не находит :todo_list_id:( No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"todo_items", :id=>"166", :todo_list_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:todo_list_id]

Comment: @Kseniya обновила ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Еще целый день попыток, и у меня получилось:) Пришлось поменять немного файл роутов, чтобы был доступ к айтемам напрямую, игнорируя :todo_list_id. Это получилось сделать с помощью shallow: true do. Также нужно было в TodoListsController в def index дополнительно объявить @todo_items, а в самом индексном файле немного поправить строку с collection. Я ночивек в rails и ничего не знала про collection, и даже не копала бы в эту сторону. Без вас у меня бы точно ушло еще минимум недели 2, спасибо огромное))